# What is the C# equivalent of this Python/Keras code?

Tags: python, c#, deedle

I am trying to partially convert some Python/Keras code to C# using Keras.NET.

```
...

changes = df[["open_changes", "high_changes", "low_changes"]].values

X = []
Y = []

for i in range(len(changes) - 21, 0, -1):
    Y.append(changes[i+20,0])
    X.append(np.array(changes[i:i+20]))
    
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 20, 3)
Y = np.array(Y)

...
```

where "changes" is in original a dataframe with 3 columns of another dataframe.

```
print(changes)

[[ 2.98969072e-02  2.98969072e-02 -2.57731959e-03]
 [-3.90390390e-02 -2.91291291e-02 -7.75193798e-03]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -1.02072379e-02 -1.04166667e-02]
 ...
 [-6.93083505e-03  3.27677700e-02  1.20471767e-05]
 [ 3.31993647e-02 -6.95852535e-03  2.28291249e-02]
 [-8.89789548e-03 -8.07462063e-03 -3.64180300e-02]]
```

X and Y are the inputs of a LSTM model where Y contains the values of "open_changes" (that should be predicted) and X a sequence of 20 datasets ("open_changes", "high_changes" and "low_changes") before to learn from

```
print(Y[0])
print(X[0])

-0.00889789548466735
[[ 9.06883161e-03  9.28074246e-03  1.37642130e-02]
 [ 4.46459714e-03 -1.14942529e-03  6.49350649e-03]
 [-1.11581823e-02 -6.24856157e-03 -6.13489736e-03]
 [ 2.86784502e-03  3.50869067e-03 -1.44818063e-02]
 [ 6.74642544e-03  0.00000000e+00  2.21317365e-02]
 [ 1.92457074e-03  3.92337872e-03 -8.17828186e-03]
 [-9.25722353e-04  7.40229885e-03  1.12581217e-02]
 [ 8.32763873e-03 -1.65442015e-03 -6.25328552e-02]
 [-5.59741781e-02 -3.26860878e-02  1.99875389e-02]
 [ 2.37391251e-02 -4.59599003e-03  1.52222249e-02]
 [-4.27878673e-04 -1.42433234e-03 -1.02286402e-02]
 [-1.38168847e-02 -1.80672768e-03 -3.64741641e-02]
 [ 2.42349707e-03  1.16339994e-02  4.47823344e-02]
 [ 1.70678021e-02  5.29692190e-04 -1.10025483e-02]
 [-4.11551834e-03 -8.23529412e-03  1.22118015e-02]
 [-5.09440684e-03 -3.08422301e-03 -4.37940353e-03]
 [-6.33795252e-03 -2.26082818e-03 -3.21114814e-03]
 [ 5.21321321e-03  2.33750745e-03  9.08096280e-03]
 [-6.93083505e-03  3.27677700e-02  1.20471767e-05]
 [ 3.31993647e-02 -6.95852535e-03  2.28291249e-02]]
```

Because the Pandas.NET library actually does not support functionality I need I decided to use Deedle.Frame which is really great:

```
var df = GetPreparedDataFrame(filePath);

IEnumerable<string> columns = new List<string>() { "open_changes", "high_changes", "low_changes" };
var changes = df.Columns[columns];
```

where "GetPreparedDataFrame(...)" simply reads a CSV file and makes some data manipulation in the Deedle.Frame.

But now, I don't know how to go on.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Sebastian.

Comment: What does your Python code actually do? Can you give a sample input and what you want to get as the result?

Comment: X and Y are the inputs for a simple LSTM model. Y contains the data of column 'open_changes' of row i and X contains a sequence of data of row i+1 to i+21 (to say the next 20 data sets) of all 3 columns to learn from. I reshape X to an Numpy array of per 20 and 3 dimensions which is actually the values of these 3 columns. I don't know if I describe it clearly. If you want I could send you my Jupyter NB and CSV file.

Comment: If you can edit your question and include a small sample data table as an input (your `changes`) and the resulting data frames that you'd like to get (`X` and `Y`), then I think that would make your question easier to answer. The full Jupyter notebook is probably too complex to be worth sharing.

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample data. However, this is still quite hard to answer, because you cannot see what's going on just by looking at the numbers. Can you show what you're trying to do using some easy to understand input data (say, containing `0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5` etc.?)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I am using TensorFlow.NET in my project. NumSharp is one of its dependencies which will be used here:

```
using NumSharp;
```

and then:

```
var (X, Y) = GetNpArray(changes);

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 20, 3);
Y = np.array(Y);
```

where GetNpArray(...) is defined as follows:

```
    private static (NDArray, NDArray) GetNpArray(Frame<int, string> dataFrame)
    {
        var X = new List<float[]>();
        var Y = new List<float>();

        for (var i = 0; i < dataFrame.RowCount - 20; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                var x1 = Convert.ToDouble(dataFrame["open_changes", i + j]);
                var x2 = Convert.ToDouble(dataFrame["high_changes", i + j]);
                var x3 = Convert.ToDouble(dataFrame["low_changes", i + j]);

                X.Add(new[] { (float)x1, (float)x2, (float)x3 });
            }

            var y = Convert.ToDouble(dataFrame["open", i + 20]);

            Y.Add((float)y);
        }

        return (np.array(X.ToArray()), np.array(Y.ToArray()));
    }
```

This gives me exactly what I need.

Regards.
Sebastian.